# Add data to MySQL when button is click, not when the page is loaded

Tags: php, mysql, youtube-api

I have a page where you can add videos to your playlist. this is done by clicking on add button.

however the problem is every-time i go to this page regardless of clinking the add button, it adds that video to yourplay list even if its already there.

You have to have an account to use the playlist feature. the add button is visible when your are logged in, and if not legged in then you dont see the add button.

here is my code for adding to the database:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){


                echo '<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="video.php" onClick="Confirm(this.form)">ADD</button>';

                $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
                $ID = $watch;
                $artist = $new[0];
                $title = $new[1];
                $youtubeID = $code;
                include 'opendb.php';
                $sql = "insert into youtube_playlist (userid,youtubeID,artist,title) values ((select id from users where username = \"$userID\"),\"$youtubeID\",\"$artist\",\"$title\")";
                $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

            }
            //if not logged in.
            else{
                echo "You are not logged in, you cant use the playlist feature.";
            }
```

so even when you are logged in and trying to watch a video its adds it to the playlist even if you dont want to. 
how do you make sure that this never happens??

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?  Perhaps you should refer to [how HTML forms work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML).  You also seem to have a vast misunderstanding about the interaction between HTML and PHP.  PHP generates HTML.  You've done nothing to glue the browser action taken when the user hits that `<button>` with any PHP code...

Comment: Also: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
        $ID = $watch;
        $artist = $new[0];
        $title = $new[1];
        $youtubeID = $code;
        include 'opendb.php';
        $sql = "insert into youtube_playlist (userid,youtubeID,artist,title) values ((select id from users where username = \"$userID\"),\"$youtubeID\",\"$artist\",\"$title\")";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "<form action='' method='post'>
            <input name='add' type='submit' value='Add'/>
        </form>";
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged in, you cant use the playlist feature.";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: -1, this isn't a good answer. Oh, I mean it *works* and all, but you haven't explained what you changed, or why it was changed, or how it helps, or how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Charles.. This was actually my first answer and im still getting the hang of this site. I will take this into consideration for future answers. Thanks!

Comment: No need to take it into consideration in the *future*, you can edit it right now!  Or later.  Or tomorrow.  You should see an edit link above these comments, on the left.